# Why does the operator overloading fail when i try to sum a number plus a matrix? (but it works the opposite way)

Tags: c++, constructor, operator-overloading

Here's the code of my matrix class:

```
class Matrix3{
public:
    double matrix [3][3];
```

The needed constructors and the + operator:

```
Matrix3::Matrix3(double num){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = num;
}

Matrix3::Matrix3(const Matrix3 &other){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            this->matrix[i][j] = other.matrix[i][j];
}

Matrix3 Matrix3::operator+(const Matrix3& other) const{
    Matrix3 temp(*this);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            temp.matrix[i][j] += other.matrix[i][j];

    return temp;
}
```

main:

```
    Matrix3 a1;     // All Elements are 0 (default)
    Matrix3 a2(a1); // a2 initialize with a1
    Matrix3 a4(4);  // All Elements are 4

    a1 = a1 + 3;   //it works
    a2 = 3 + a2;   //it doesn't, it says: "invalid operands to binary expression"
    a4 = a1 + a2;  //it works too
```

So i don't understand why does the first one work. in both case it should create a matrix in which all elemets are 3 because there is a constructor for that and add it to the onether matrix.
Any idea?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem -- `Matrix3::Matrix3(double num)` will be better as an explicit constructor. Implicit conversion of a `double` to a `Matrix3` does not feel right to me.

Comment: It was a task at university (I'm a beginner) and I had to write a matrix class that can be defined by an array out of 9 elements or a single number and in that case all the numbers in the matrix must be that single num.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because you declared operator+ as a member function. This is a bad idea because of exactly the problem you have found. When operator+ is a member function the C++ compiler will do automatic conversions on the right hand side but not on the left hand side.

Fix this by making your operator+ a global function with two arguments

```
Matrix3 operator+(const Matrix3& lhs, const Matrix3& rhs) {
    ...
}
```

Now the conversion from `double` to `Matrix` will be done on either argument.

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't work but I guess I've just missed something because it works now. Thanks.

Comment: How is it automatically able to convert from a double object to a "matrix" object when no such conversion operator is explicitly defined in the matrix class

Comment: @PiyushSingh The conversion happens because of the non-explicit constructor `Matrix3::Matrix3(double num){`

Comment: I see. It is using one of the constructors as a conversion operator; it works because that constructor takes a double as argument. But suppose I say `int b=5; a1=a1+b;`. Then will it cast int to double and double to matrix?

Comment: @PiyushSingh I believe that only one automatic conversion is applied. But the rules are complicated, I could easily be wrong.

Comment: @PiyushSingh any constructor that takes a single argument (and is not declared `explicit`) is called a [converting constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) because it is considered for implicit conversions

Comment: @PiyushSingh conversion operators are for converting `Matrix3` to other types, converting constructors for other types to `Matrix3`

Comment: @idclev463035818 I don't think you can convert something to a built-in type. For example a function with signature `void test(double x)` would throw an error when a custom class's object is passed into it: `Matrix3 a; test(a);` would throw some no matching function found type error. Wouldnt it?

Comment: @PiyushSingh you could write a `operator int ()` for your matrix, then it would work (whether this makes sense is a different question of couse, in general i prefer to avoid implicit conversions). Sorry for pushing this in to slightly off topic....